# How to trace the multiprocesses C progaram

Tags: c, process

I am learning multi-processes in C programs in Linux. There is such an example code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int pid1 = fork();
  printf("**1**\n");
  int pid2 = fork();
  printf("**2**\n");
  if (pid1 == 0) {
    int pid3 = fork();
    printf("**3**\n");
  } else
    printf("**4**\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I know there is something interesting in the program and the output is sometimes different because of the child processes. However, I am confused   when I want to explain the detailed process to others.

What is the clear process of this example code ? Or **is there any way or any utils to track the program and help me figure out the detailed runtime information?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way to help understand the `printf` output is to prefix your messages with PID. E.g. `printf("%d **1**\n", getpid());`

Comment: Also, when printing after a `fork`, you may only want to print in the _child_. In your example, you'll get _two_ `**3**` messages (i.e. the parent that forks the child prints and so does the child). Perhaps more meaningful with: `int pid3 = fork(); if (pid3 == 0) printf("%d: **3**\n",getpid());`

Comment: Insert a long `sleep()` before `return 0` and use the time to display the process tree. On Linux, you can use command `pstree` to visualize the process tree.